# understanding javascript function in XKCD

Tags: javascript

I am trying to view individual tiles from this comic: http://xkcd.com/1110/

I looked at the JavaScript but I can't figure out the naming convention.

```
for (var y = -1; y <= +1; y++)
    for (var x = -1; x <= +1; x++) {
        var name = tile_name(centre[0] + x, centre[1] + y);
        var tile = $map.find('.tile' + name);
        if (tile.length) $remove = $remove.not(tile);
        else {
            $image = $('<img class="tile' + name + '" src="http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/' + name + '.png" style="top:' + ((centre[1] + y) * tilesize) + 'px;left:' + ((centre[0] + x) * tilesize) + 'px; z-index: -1; position: absolute;;" style="display:none" />');
            $image.load(function() {
                $(this).show()
            }).error(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $map.append($image);
        }
    }

$remove.remove();
```

I was expecting: http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1.2.png but that doesn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://forums.xkcd.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=91362

Comment: Not sure whether the question is 'what is the convention' or 'what does this JS do' or 'why can't I derive the convention for this?'. The convention is http://imgs.xkcd.com/clickdrag/1n2w.png , where 1 and 2 can be changed, but I got that just by using Firebug. Either way, this seems an exceedingly narrow query.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this Function:
Its creates the name of the tile.

```
    tile_name=function(x,y)
    {
        x-=size[3];
        y-=size[0];
        return (y>=0?(y+1)+'s':-y+'n')+(x>=0?(x+1)+'e':-x+'w')
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The naming scheme is `\dn\dw`, so for example, 2n2w. Beware, some are missing.